# How to visualize a blow up of a StreamPlot near an almost singular point

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization, singularity

I have a two dimensional (SIR) dynamical system with three fixed points. At one of them, E0, one eigenvalue is almost 0, and the `StreamPlot` needs a blow-up

```
dyn2 = {-((i s \[Beta])/(1 + i \[Xi])) + \[CapitalLambda] - 
   s \[Mu], -((i \[Alpha])/(i + \[Omega])) + (i s \[Beta])/(
   1 + i \[Xi]) - i (\[Gamma] + \[Delta] + \[Mu])}; eqF = 
 Thread[Flatten[dyn2 == 0]];
JacF = Grad[(dyn2), {s, i}] // FullSimplify;
test = {\[CapitalLambda] -> 16, \[Delta] -> 1/5, \[Gamma] -> 3/
    25, \[Beta] -> 1/100, \[Xi] -> 1/1000, \[Mu] -> 1/10, 
   Subscript[v, 2] -> \[Gamma] + \[Delta] + \[Mu], 
   Subscript[v, 1] -> \[Beta] + \[Xi] \[Mu], \[Omega] -> 1/
    4, \[Alpha] -> 115/32};
solF = Solve[eqF, {s, i}] //. test // N
JacE2 = JacF //. test //. {s -> (s /. solF[[2]]), 
    i -> (i /. solF[[2]])};

JacE0 = JacF //. {s -> (s /. solF[[1]]), i -> 0};
Print["eig.val at E0 are :", Eigenvalues[JacE0] //. test // N]
epi1 = {Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)", 
    Offset[{10, 10}, {(s /. solF[[1]]), 0}]], {PointSize[Large], 
    Style[Point[{(s /. solF[[1]]), 0}], Green]}, 
   Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(2\)]\)", 
    Offset[{0, 
      10}, {(s /. solF[[2]]), (i /. solF[[2]])}]], {PointSize[Large], 
    Style[Point[{(s /. solF[[2]]), (i /. solF[[2]])}], Blue]}, 
   Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(1\)]\)", 
    Offset[{-10, 11}, {(s /. solF[[3]]), 
      i /. solF[[3]]}]], {PointSize[Large], 
    Style[Point[{(s /. solF[[3]]), i /. solF[[3]]}], Purple]}};
sp = StreamPlot[{dyn2 //. test}, {s, 30, 200}, {i, -0.0001, 60}, 
  Epilog -> {epi1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"s", "i"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Medium]]
bupE0 = StreamPlot[dyn2 //. test, {s, 154, 166}, {i, -0.0001, 0.05}, 
  Epilog -> epi1, ImageSize -> 300, StreamColorFunction -> Hue,  
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"s", "i"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Medium]]
```

The blow-up only shows one vertical line, which stops in mid-air (I also get sometimes several parallel lines). Is it possible to get a better visualization, showing several lines with arrows towards E0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use "VectorPlot" instead of "StreamPlot":

```
VectorPlot[Evaluate[dyn2 //. test], {s, 159, 161}, {i, -0.005, 0.005},
  Epilog -> epi1, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"s", "i"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Medium], 
 StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

[image]